# Grabbing the nearest ul to a button

Tags: jquery

I have a button that toggles some items on and off and I'm trying to make this the most dynamic as possible because I could have multiple of these per page and I would like to use the same function.

My issue is, I'm trying to call the nearest `ul` when this button is clicked, but I have a form and a few paragraphs between the button and the `ul`.

```
<button class="showProduction"></button>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="" value="" />
  </form>
  <p class="clearfix"></p>
<ul class="rawFiles">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

I have so far tried

```
 $('.showProduction').closest('ul');

 $('.showProduction').closest('.rawFiles');
```

and a few complex `.find()`'s but I know I was just thinking too much with those in an effort to get anything to work.

Comment: Have you tried next() ?

Comment: yes, but that only worked if it was a direct sibling

Comment: It's easier if you wrap all your structure (form, p, ul) in a container and semantically it would make more sense too

Comment: @koala_dev That would be the best, but I cant because of how huge this is and how dynamic it has to be. I cant depend on that container to be there every time I need to show more of something.

Comment: @zazvorniki if it's going to be varying structure, wrapping is the only way that makes sense. Then can look within closest wrapper

Comment: @charlietfl To put it nicely, I'm not working with the brightest bulbs in the box and I know they will not wrap anything I ask them to. I can only go by the exact variables and classes in the actual elements. It's either that or I go crazy putting divs in a million different places...and honestly I like my sanity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('.showProduction').nextAll("ul.rawFiles:first").find('...')
```

So :

```
$(".showProduction").on('click',function (){

   //do something with :   $(this).nextAll("ul.rawFiles:first").find('...')

});
```

Example : this will print the value of the first following UL (LI's) value.

http://jsbin.com/iJOsosa/8/edit

edit : (after OP clarification )

http://jsbin.com/iJOsosa/5/edit

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work, in the console.log it returns an empty array and in my click function it's just not finding it at all.

Comment: @zazvorniki wait ill paste an example

Comment: @zazvorniki look at my edit. it will print the value of the first li.

Comment: I'm still not getting to work within my code though, I have tried exactly that, and I have also tried changing the background color $('.showProduction').nextAll('ul.rawFiles:first').css('background', 'green');

Comment: @zazvorniki you want to change the color for the first LI of the first UL or the whole UL ?

Comment: In reality I have a super complex adding and removing files that I have to attach to it. I was just using a background color as an example. It really should look like something like this      $(this).nextAll('ul.rawFiles:first li:lt(' + x + ')').css('display', 'inline-block');